# Server 2003/ NAT server 2003 IP mapping issue

Tags: windows-server-2003

I configured NAT server 2003, 5 public IP are available that one of them is
used for the network card. In the IP pooling, I have entered the public IP
addresses, and I set the IP that has been used for the server network card as a
reserved one, I realized some of the client randomly cannot browser internet of
course they can ping. Those clients in the show IP mapping have been mapped to the
reserved IP???
Could you please help me what is the problem,

Comment: -1 bad formatted question. I'm assuming your server is public facing and you're not using a firewall? If you can ping and not browse the internet, that's DNS. So what is your actual question here? Is it NAT isn't working? Is it access to the internet for PCs?

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have only assigned one public IP the NIC doing NAT. The idea of NAT is that is converts the source IP address to the source public IP address of the NAT device. Since you have only assigned one public IP it can only ever NAT the private IP's to this IP address. What you need to do is assign all the public IP's to the internet side facing NIC then create one to one NATs in RRAS for your clients. See here as well http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/re-one-one-nat-problem-t1897845.html